# response size in load runner

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I am testing a webservice where based on different promo code I am retrieving multiple offers each promo code. Now I did parameterization for promo code, Now I need to get response time for each request. Where I can get these details.

Answer (score 0):

Training.  You can find the response time by taking in person training, by taking computer based training, by going through the downloadable tutorial or by reading the PDF versions of the Virtual User Generator users guide.